# can not find tkSnack.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tcl

I set up my conda env on my Mac with python2.7, tk 8.6.7 and snack 0.0.3, but I still can't exec

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
import tkSnack
```

It says

```
ImportError: No module named tkSnack
```

`locate tkSnack` returns nothing.
`locate snack` returns:

```
/System/Library/Tcl/8.4/snack2.2
/System/Library/Tcl/8.4/snack2.2/libsnack2.2.dylib
/System/Library/Tcl/8.4/snack2.2/pkgIndex.tcl
/System/Library/Tcl/8.4/snack2.2/snack.tcl
```

The funny thing is there is both Tcl/8.4 and 8.5, but the tk in my env is 8.6.7. Is that a sign of trouble?

What is my problem here?

Comment: Looks like `tkSnack.py` isn't present at all, let alone in somewhere on your `PYTHONPATH`…

Answer (score 1):

tkSnack is an interface to Kare Sjolander's Snack Tcl extension. You can find the code at [Download page](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/download.html).

A way to install tcltk snack is using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tksnack
```

Note: This will install the binary in the default computer path, conda maybe no detect them.

The file tkSnack.py is contain in repository source code, [lastest version](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/dist/snack2.2.10.tar.gz), inside python library. You have 2 ways to install python file if you are using conda, 1º you will have to put tkSnack.py in `${your_env_folder}/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. To know where is the base path use `conda info --env`. Alternativally, use command `python setup.py install` in python path directly.

If you have problems with conda, try installing so in the conda enviroment or moving them directly: `cp /usr/lib/tcltk/snack2.2/* ${your_env_folder}/lib/`

This is not a easy way, but works. If you want more info, check the [official documentation](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/index.html)

Comment: I don't have Conda.. So How can I install?

Comment: You do not need conda, the command will work, did you tried it?

Comment: How can I use it? I have use it with `apt-get` but i not worked...

Comment: That package is a sound extension to Tcl/Tk and Python/Tkinter for Python 2.x library. Python v2 is not longer maintained.

Comment: oh I use python3, sad :(

Comment: You may try to google your problem, if you search "tkSnack Python3" it seems it exist a version tk for Python 3. Try `sudo apt install python3-tksnack` and run your Python script.